# Regex for multiple string operations in a single pass?

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I do the following in a single `gsub` what is the `regex` to get the desired output?

```
string = "Make all the changes within a single pass"
string.gsub(/[^aeiou|\s]/, '*').gsub(/\s/, '&')
 #=> "*a*e&a**&**e&**a**e*&*i**i*&a&*i***e&*a**"
```

- First `gsub` if it's not a **vowel** or a **space** replace it
  with `*`
- Second `gsub` If it's a **space** replace it with a `&`

The reason I ask is because I feel like chaining `gsub` is not the *right* way to do this. Please let me know if you think this is a good way..

Comment: Two seperate replace conditions. You could use a callback if ruby has that, but it would take just as much time. `/([^aeiou\s])|(\s)/` then check group 1 or 2 matched.

Comment: I smell homework or an assignment.

Comment: @tin Just a learning experience. No homework or assignment. Simply self fulfillment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) to do the substitution in a single pass. This assumes the string consists of printable ASCII characters.

```
string.tr " \t\nB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Zb-df-hj-np-tv-z!-@[-`{-~", '&&&*'
# => "*a*e&a**&**e&**a**e*&*i**i*&a&*i***e&*a**"
```

For `tr`, `-` is the range operator. So for the letters `B`, `C`, `D`, since these are consecutive, it can be written as `B-D`. So `B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z` is basically all the capital letters minus the vowels. Same with lowercase, followed by all printable punctuation on the ASCII chart. These all get replaced by a `*`. The only 3 whitespace characters that match `\s` are space, tab, and newline, and these are listed explicitly at the front of the string and are each replaced by `&`.

---

If 2 passes are allowed, then it can be written more concisely as

```
string.tr(' ','&').tr('^AEIOUaeiou&','*')
```

Comment: I updated my answer with `string#tr` method. Super fast. Check it out. Thanks for the tip. Your `tr` is even faster than mine but for the sake of readability I had to alter it. You speak machine to well. Please help us understand what all this is: `" \t\nB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Zb-df-hj-np-tv-z!-@[-`{-~"`

Comment: @feed_me_code Answer updated. Yes this deserves to be spelled out.

Comment: now that makes perfect sense. Just wondering why `'&&&*'` ? Is this supposed to aid readability? Because all of the following seem to work: `'&, *'` or `'&{3}*'` or `'&|*'` or `'& *'`

Comment: @feed_me_code No, each character matches the other according to index. For example, `&, *` would replace a tab `\t` with a comma `,` since they are the second characters in each of their respective strings. The last character `*` is repeated to match everything else. Check out [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) for a better description.

Comment: I read that too which is odd because I'm testing it and it works as expected. `'&, *'` Try it.

Comment: @feed_me_code If I apply that to `"Make\tall"` then it replaces the tab `"\t"` with a comma `,` as expected. The space ` ` is still replaced by a `&` because that is the first character.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured out I can pass a `block` like this:

```
string.gsub(/[^aeiou]/) {|g| g =~ /\s/ ? "&" : "*"}
 #=> "*a*e&a**&**e&**a**e*&*i**i*&a&*i***e&*a**"
```

I prefer the solution above but this also works:

```
string.gsub(/[^aeiou|\s]/, '*').gsub(/\s/, '&')
 #=> "*a*e&a**&**e&**a**e*&*i**i*&a&*i***e&*a**"
```

**Benchmark results (corrected): Using `Benchmark` class** (900k length string sample size)

```
Benchmark.measure { string.gsub(/[^aeiou]/) {|g| g =~ /\s/ ? "&" : "*"} }
  #=> 0.800000   0.010000   0.810000 ( 0.801419 )

Benchmark.measure { string.gsub(/[^aeiou|\s]/, '*').gsub(/\s/, '&') }
  #=> 0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 ( 0.231482 )
```

Looks like the second option is many times faster and the clear winner in speed and appears to have the preferred readability.

**Update**

Based on @Matt's answer I also was able to use: [`string#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) **This solution is blazing fast (fastest of all tested) string @900k char size.**

```
string.tr(' ', '&').tr('^[aeiou|&]', '*')
Benchmark.measure { string.tr(' ', '&').tr('^[aeiou|&]', '*') }
  #=> 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 ( 0.015000 )
```

Comment: I like the first one. Hard to say which wins on the benches.

Comment: You can benchmark it easily. Read the documentation for the Benchmark class, or look at the Fruity gem.

Comment: My benchmark shows two `gsub`s being over twice as fast. That looks more readable to me, as well.

Comment: @Max it's actually multiple times faster. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In the `tr` function you can drop the 3 characters `[|]` since `^` negates all characters that follow it, just as in a [RegExp character class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes).

Answer (score 0):

```
string.gsub(/(\s)|([^aeiou])/){$1 ? "&" : "*"}
# => "*a*e&a**&**e&**a**e*&*i**i*&a&*i***e&*a**"
```

Comment: Like it but super slow. I updated my answer using `string#tr` as per Matt's suggestion. And it is blazing fast. Thanks.